# Time interval in clojurescript using Klipse and Reagent going very (too) fast

Tags: clojurescript

Hi I'm trying my hand at ClojureScript and I'm using [Klipse](https://github.com/viebel/klipse) as my REPL pretty much. It's maybe not it's intended use but because I don't do anything too complicated it's fine for now.

One problem I have is trying to setup a timer. My code is:

```
(ns my.reagent-examples
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))

(when-let [element (js/document.getElementById "app")]
  (r/render-component [component] element))

;; State
(def app-state (r/atom 0)) ;; Initial value is 0

;; Increment seconds
(js/setInterval #(swap! app-state inc) 1000) ;; Increment app-state every 1000ms

;; "Seconds elapsed" component 
(defn timer []
  [:div (str "Seconds elapsed: " @app-state)])
```

It show a timer but it's too fast and seems to accelerate as time goes by. Intended result would be a counter incrementing every second.

My full Klipse file is like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/app.klipse.tech/css/codemirror.css">
  <script>
    window.klipse_settings = {
      selector: '.language-klipse', // css selector for the html elements you want to klipsify
      selector_reagent: '.language-reagent', // selector for reagent snippets
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <pre><code class="language-reagent">
(ns my.reagent-examples
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))
(when-let [element (js/document.getElementById "app")]
  (r/render-component [component] element))
;; State
(def app-state (r/atom 0)) ;; Initial value is 0
;; Increment seconds
(js/setInterval #(swap! app-state inc) 1000) ;; Increment app-state every 1000ms
;; "Seconds elapsed" component 
(defn timer []
  [:div (str "Seconds elapsed: " @app-state)])
</code></pre>

  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/app.klipse.tech/plugin/js/klipse_plugin.js"></script>
</body>
```

(Run the snippet in full page to see the timer)

EDIT: I look like a fool because in the snippet the timer look like it run normally, but when I open the exact same HTML file with Google Chrome or Firefox, the timer goes nuts.. What could be the reason for that?

EDIT2: It seems if you change things on the snippet, you'll see the timer going faster, is that because there it is rendered too many time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue probably is that when you edit and save your code, it's hot-reloaded in your browser and starts another `js/setInterval` without stopping the previous one.

You can fix it by calling `js/setInterval` in `defonce` definition that will be executed only once on first load and won't be called on reloads:

```
(defonce timer-increment-interval
  (js/setInterval #(swap! app-state inc) 1000)) ;; Increment app-state every 1000ms
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I didn't think the `js/setInterval` could stack on each other but I guess it make sense! Thank you